# Npsql: creating indexes on jsonb column with EF Core

Tags: .net, postgresql, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, npgsql

I have a standard NoSQL table in PostgreSQL: ID (`UUID`) and Data (`jsonb`). I would like to create an index on one of the properties of the JSON document that goes into the Data column. Normally I use EF Core like so:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<T>().HasIndex(e => e.ColumnToPutAnIndexOn);
```

My presumption to creating an index on a JSON property was like so:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<T>().HasIndex(e => e.Data.PropertyToPutAnIndexOn);
```

However, this gives me an error:

```
The expression should represent a simple property access: 't => t.MyProperty'.
```

The [Npgsql documentation](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/json.html#indexing-json-columns) is still a work in progress on that matter.

Did anyone figure out how to best create indexes on JSON documents short of writing raw SQL statements?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Shay, thank you for the information. Based upon the answer "it is not possible", I said to myself: hold my beer.

So I made something. Something ugly, but I made it. And it works.

Take in our case the Entity itself, containing the ID and jsonb Data column:

```c#
    public class Entity<T> where T : EntityData
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
        public T Data { get; set; }

        public Entity() : base()
        {
        }
    }
```

Note: The generic T is an EntityData, which is nothing but an empty base class for future purposes. This can be anything, really.

We can then use the `Entity<T>` class like so:

```c#
Entity<User> userEntity = new Entity<User>();
userEntity.Data.Username = "myusername"; // the .Data property is now of type User (the actual POCO/Model/JSON document)
```

The User class has properties:

```c#
    public class User : EntityData
    {
        [Index] // custom IndexAttribute class
        public string Username { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I have created an EnsureIndexes() function, this can be placed inside a custom DbContext/UnitOfWork class or where ever you'd like. This function uses reflection and iterates over the properties of the entity inside `Entity<T>.Data` and calls a raw NpgsqlCommand:

```c#
            // get DbSet<> properties of the context
            PropertyInfo[] dbsets = context.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => x.PropertyType.Name == "DbSet`1").ToArray();
            foreach (PropertyInfo dbset in dbsets)
            {
                // get the generic type of the DbSet<> property. 
                // in this case we will get the Entity<T> type
                string lowerCaseDbSetName = dbset.Name.ToLower();
                Type dbsetDataType = dbset.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

                // try to obtain the Entity<T>.Data PropertyInfo
                PropertyInfo dataProperty = dbsetDataType.GetProperty("Data");
                if (dataProperty == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                Type dataPropertyType = dataProperty.PropertyType;

                // Now iterate over the properties of the POCO/Document stored in Entity<T>.Data
                PropertyInfo[] jsonProperties = dataPropertyType.GetProperties().ToArray();
                foreach (PropertyInfo jsonProperty in jsonProperties)
                {
                    // If we can find an IndexAttribute....
                    IndexAttribute attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(jsonProperty, typeof(IndexAttribute)) as IndexAttribute;
                    if (attribute == null)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    string camelCaseProperty = jsonProperty.Name.ToCamelCase();
                    string lowerCaseProperty = jsonProperty.Name.ToLower();

                    // We will then create an SQL statement to create an index on that property. Mainaining the standard Npgsql naming format of IX_DbSet_Property
                    string sql = $"CREATE INDEX IX_{dbset.Name}_{lowerCaseProperty} ON public.\"{dbset.Name}\" ((public.\"{dbset.Name}\".\"Data\" ->> '{camelCaseProperty}'));";
                    int result = context.ExecuteNonQuery(sql); // my custom function returns -2 on an exception
                    if (result != -2)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(sql);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately indexing properties inside jsonb documents isn't as straightforward as indexing table columns... Take a look at [the PostgreSQL docs for this to get an idea](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING).

To summarize the important info, if you just want to query top-level JSON properties, then a GIN index on the column is sufficient. If you want to query deeper into the document, you have to set up an expression index, which is a different beast altogether.

Because of the complexity and different choices, the provides doesn't yet do anything for you automatically - you'll have to use raw SQL in your migrations to define the index you want (there's no problems with doing this - it's encouraged). This may change in the future, if we can provide sane index creation logic for the different jsonb scenarios.